# Equivalence of Categories between the Fundamental Group and Groupoid

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, groupoids

Let $X$ be a path connected space, and let $x \in X$. Then we have that $\pi_1 (X,x)$ is a full subcategory of $\Pi(X)$. So, the inclusion functor $J: \pi_1(X,x) \to \Pi(X)$ is an equivalence of categories.

May, in his proof of the Van Kampen Theorem, asserts the following.

> An inverse equivalence $F: \Pi(X) \to \pi_1(X,x)$ is determined by a choice of path classes $x \to y$ for $y \in X$.

I'm not sure how. I think he means that for each $y \in X$, one chooses a path class $\alpha_y :x \to y$, and using this maps a morphism $f:y \to y'$ by $F$ as follows: $$Ff := \alpha_{y'}^{-1} \circ f \circ \alpha_y$$

Is this the case?

Comment: I realized the answer to my question halfway through typing it. Decided to post it anyway. Affirmation would be nice in any case.

Comment: Then you should write an official answer so that everybody sees at first glance that the question is no longer open. Your approach is correct.

Comment: @PaulFrost Done, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having realized the answer, I'm answering my own question.

The approach in the original post is the correct one, with one slight addition; we must take $\alpha_x$ to be the identity.

The approach works in general for any groupoid, as long is it is connected. To see that the definition gives a functor, we simply see that for $g:y \to y'$ and $h: y' \to y''$, $F(h \circ g) = \alpha_{y''}^{-1} \circ h \circ g \circ \alpha_y  = F(h) \circ F(g)$ (By inserting $\alpha_{y'}\circ\alpha_{y'}^{-1}$). Note that $F$ is fully faithful and surjective.

Also, we get that this is precisely an inverse of $J$, because $F \circ J$ is $\operatorname {id}_{\pi_1(X,\, x)}$ and $J \circ F$ is naturally naturally isomorphic to the identity on $\Pi(X)$.

Comment: Just a warning: This kind of result was long interpreted as "groupoids reduce to groups".  Since the reduction involves choices, the interpretation is no more valid than "linear algebra reduces to matrix theory".  See also some remarks of Grothendieck reported in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220561/descent-theorems-for-fundamental-groups-and-groupoids